# How to show json data in a table format retrieved from node.js server using Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is an index file I had made to display the json data though angular.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th , td {
border: 1px solid grey;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 5px;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
<script src= “http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js”></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app=”” ng-controller=”blogController”>

<table>
<tr><td>Manger Id</td><td>Manger Name</td></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat=”x in name”>
    <td>{{ x.m_id }}</td>

<td>{{ x.name }}</td>


  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
function blogController($scope,$http) {
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/techgeek/v1/getEmployeeDetails')
.success(function(response) {
    $scope.names = response;
    console.log($scope.names);
});
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to get the json data from nodejs server. I aslo attacted a secreen shout my json data genereated though nodejs sever .[image]. The main problem with url. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: can u show relevant js code and {{ x.name }} should be like {{ x.m_name }}

Comment: var url = require('url');
router.get('/techgeek/v1/getEmployeeDetails', function(req, res, next) {
    try {


            //var roleId = req.param('m_id');
               //   var deptId = req.param('m_name');
          var query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
                  console.log(query);
        var roleId = query.m_id;
        var deptId = query.Name;
        console.log(roleId);
        console.log(deptId);
        req.getConnection(function(err, conn) {

Comment: so  router.get('/techgeek/v1/getEmployeeDetails',  is your call ....from this u need to return your id and name to controller and there assign it a scope and loop it in your view

Comment: @ManvenderSinghRathore check my answer below

Comment: can u show your controller code

Comment: @SaEChowdary the controller code *is* in the body of the question, but it's not obvious, because the OP is using a deprecated syntax with a stale version of angular from September, 2015.  Angular changes so fast that in my opinion, you do yourself a disservice by starting a new project with a stale framework version, and I recommend bringing code up to current standards before even trying to troubleshoot any other issues that may or may not exist in the current release branch.

Comment: also, is this your *exact* code? because you seem to have issues here with the HTML;  you aren't using the `""` character, you are using `””` which isn't interpreted the same.

Comment: I am using sublime 2 as text editor.. its autogenerate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the live for your problem. I have solved it using the local Json. 
You have made the following mistakes as below

1. **ng-repeat** names should be there as you have $scope.names in your controller.
2. **x.name** in the second column which is wrong as your json is having the **x.m_name** as the field.
3. Also, I have a doubt if the node.js server and the angular application is running in the same port, else you might get **CORS**(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) error in the console which you have to fix it.

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/QPqzuvWEim4xGnvWwNy5?p=preview)

```
   <tr><td>Manger Id</td><td>Manger Name</td></tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="x in names track by $index">
        <td>{{ x.m_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.m_name }}</td>
   </tr>
```

### Update 1

You have a problem with the module as you have used `ng-app=""` in your code please fix it by using a module as below

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller("",function(){
 .....................
});
```

Comment: this is obviously correct way .....but i think he struck with sending response to controller.....

Comment: are you using the same port number **3000**

Comment: @Aravind you can see the screen shot, I had uploaded.

Comment: happy to help you :P

Comment: Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011625/output-is-not-being-shown-using-angularjs-when-data-is-retrieved-from-nodejs/47011677?noredirect=1#comment80970867_47011677